# Convert Java code to C#

Tags: java, c#

I want to convert this java code to C# code 
Can any one help me please ? thanks in advance

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));  
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());  
Date dateGMT= cal.getTime();
```

Comment: So you want C# to give you the current GMT time?

Comment: yes bathsheba thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm that expert with c# (had some background with it though..), but you may try this code if you want to get the current utc time:

```
DateTime dt= DateTime.UtcNow;//get the UTC/GMT time now... 

//different time formats... 
dt.ToString("HH:mm"); // 07:00 // 24 hour clock // hour is 
//always 2 digits
dt.ToString("hh:mm tt"); // 07:00 AM // 12 hour clock // //hour 
//is always 2 digits
dt.ToString("H:mm"); // 7:00 // 24 hour clock
dt.ToString("h:mm tt"); // 7:00 AM // 12 hour clock
Console.Write(dt); //print result or you can do something about the result..
```

I have tried to write the different format then print it. I hope I have helped you. Don't hesitate to comment if you have further questions

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.UtcNow` is one way.

Luckily `.UtcNow` (Coordinated Universal Time) is *always* GMT (excepting leap-seconds).

C# has an absolutely gigantic library. The best place to start is its documentation.

Comment: Thanks
what about this dear?
Date publishTime;
 publishTime.getTime();

Comment: publishtime cumming as parameter  I want same function as gettime in java?